# Symfony2 login authentication

Tags: symfony, authentication, doctrine

I'm trying to restrict users from going to anything within /admin/ and if they attempt to then they will be redirected to /login.

At the moment I can get to the login page which is using a traditional login form and if I submit it I get an error returned saying 'Bad Credentials', therefore the /login_check seems to be working correctly. However, if I go to /admin/ or /admin/foo it doesn't redirect to /login. Instead it says 'No route found for GET /admin/'.

My security.yml file is:

> jms_security_extra:
>       secure_all_services: false
>       expressions: true

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN:
providers:
    administrators:
                entity: { class: XXXBundle:AdminUser, property: email }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    admin_area:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        form_login:
          login_path:  /login
          check_path:  /admin/login_check
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
  - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My routing.yml file is:

```
login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: XXXBundleSecurity:login }
login_check:
    pattern:   /admin/login_check
```

Comment: Do you really have your `/admin/XXX` routes?

Comment: Do I need to create a route for each admin page i.e /admin/users ?

Comment: Ahh so I do! Thanks for your help!! If you would like to leave it as an answer I will set it as correct?

Comment: As a tip you may find useful.  Keep all of your admin routes in a separate file, and in your main routing file, include the admin routing file using the resource option, and specify the /admin prefix for the include route.  That way you don't have to specify /admin explicitly for each individual admin route.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Out of interest, would you use the same controller for admin and frontend? I.e say I have pages which can be added/updated etc in the admin section and they will obviously be used on the front end i.e About Us etc, would you put all these in one PageController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/admin/XXX routes are unneccessary. If you have  set

```
pattern:    ^/admin
```

/admin/XXX should be redirected to /login.
more details see http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise I had to specify the route, I thought the firewall would simply catch anything that began with /admin/

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're missing both routes you're trying to access. Try to add this to your routing.yml:

```
admin:
    resource: "@XXXBundle/Controller/Admin.php"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
```

I like [Routes using Annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) very much so I used that in this example.

Then in your Admin.php you can use something like:

```
// XXXBundle/Controller/Admin.php

namespace XXXBundle/Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="admin_index")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
       // Code goes here
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/foo ", name="admin_foo")
     */
    public function fooAction(Request $request)
    {
       // Code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Out of interest, would you use the same controller for admin and frontend? I.e say I have pages which can be added/updated etc in the admin section and they will obviously be used on the front end i.e About Us etc, would you put all these in one PageController?

Comment: You're welcome. I prefer to create a new bundle for backends to keep things seperated (I would say that admin pages belong to the backend too). Because in the end you'll not only end up with admin-specific controllers but with admin-specific templates, forms, models etc. And you'll be glad to have them seperated in the first place.